# Error: Invalid vs_2_0 output semantic

Tags: hlsl

Its says: `Invalid vs_2_0` output semantic `SV_Target`.

So for some reason Visual Studio 2017 is compiling my pixel shader as if it is a vertex shader. But in the properties panel I specified it to be a ps_5_0. Is there something I'm missing that should be specified?

Vertex shader:-

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
    matrix World;
    matrix View;
    matrix Projection;
}

struct Input {
    float3 Pos  : POSITION;
    float4 Color: COLOR;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

VS_OUTPUT main(Input input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output = (VS_OUTPUT)0;

    output.Pos = mul(input.Pos, World);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, View);
    output.Pos = mul(output.Pos, Projection);

    output.Color = input.Color;
    return output;
}
```

Pixel shader:-

```
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

float4 main(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_Target
{
    return input.Color;
}
```

And [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02dHp.png) are my settings for the pixel shader.
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Have you check the target and platform in the property panel, VS2017 has a breaking change in behavior from past version and the panel does not open with the current IDE setting anymore and keep track of his own.

Answer (score 14):

Open the Property page for the *.hlsl* file, and in **HLSL Compiler/General/Shader Type** select **Pixel Shader**.

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to set this propertie for debug and release.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by modifying the `shader` property

`properties -> HLSL Compiler -> General -> Shader Type -> Pixel Shader (/ps)`

OR

`Configuration properties -> General -> Excluded from Build = Yes.`